# ¿Cómo resaltar un campo según su valor listado?

Tags: php, javascript

necesito resaltar con un color especifico la el campo según un valor, pero no se como realizarlo si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería es para un trabajo.

tengo este código que me lista información de mi tabla-

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered" style="font-size:10px;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="width:5%;">nivel</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">especialidad</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">rut</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">rut_2</th>
      <th style="width:15%;">nombres</th>
      <th style="width:5%;">estado</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody id="myTable">
    <tr>
        


        <?php
    
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM SAE WHERE mat_estado='1' ORDER BY nivel ASC;";
        $resultado = mysql_query($consulta,$link);
        while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)){
        ?>  
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $fila['nivel']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['especialidad']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['rut']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['rut_2']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['nombres']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $fila['estado']; ?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php
    }       
    ?>      
      
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

y me entrega este resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y necesito que se resalte de un color especifico según lo que indique en el ultimo campo algo asi como ALUMNO CONTINUA resaltado en verde, ALUMNO SE VA resaltado en rojo

quedo atento a los comentario, saludos y espero que me sepan entender y ayudar.

Comment: Recuerda siempre evitar el uso de mayúsculas sostenidas ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías comenzar capturando el valor de celda y compararlo, luego simplemente le agregas el estilo que deseas, algo como esto.

Le puse un `id` para poder seleccionarlo, dentro seleccione la etiqueta `tr`, finalmente capturo el valor de cada fila la cual la recorro con un `for`, y dando asi la comparacion de la celda con el tipo de  especialidad, tu puedes hacerlo con el que desees.

```js
var table = document.getElementById("tablita");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var z = 1; z < rows.length; z++) {
    if(rows[z].cells[1].innerHTML == 'CONTABILIDAD'){
      rows[z].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }else{
      rows[z].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="tablita" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>nivel</th>
      <th>especialidad</th>
      <th>rut</th>
      <th>rut_2</th>
      <th>nombres</th>
      <th>estado</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody id="myTable">
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>CONTABILIDAD</td>
          <td>72558468</td>
          <td>75845854</td>
          <td>FELIPE</td>
          <td>ESTADO 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>SISTEMAS</td>
          <td>72558468</td>
          <td>75845854</td>
          <td>FELIPE</td>
          <td>ESTADO 1</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: estimado @Felipe Urcia gracias por la respuesta pero disculpa mi ignorancia pero estoy recién aprendiendo.  como se incorpora este código

var table = document.getElementById("tablita");
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
for (var z = 1; z < rows.length; z++) {
    if(rows[z].cells[1].innerHTML == 'CONTABILIDAD'){
      rows[z].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }else{
      rows[z].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}

Comment: Tendrias que colocarlo entre etiquetas de `<script></script>` en la pagina donde estara la tabla.

Comment: asi como lo planteas me funciono perfecto pero cuando lo implemento en mi código no me da ningún resultado